# makefile : find recursively and delete auxiliary files

Tags: makefile, find

Assume I have a list of file known by their extention:

```
EXT=*ext1 *ext2 *ext3
```

I want to use in my makefile something like

```
clean:$(EXT)
    find . -name @< -delete
```

But I can't make it work because I need to use the find command for each extension is EXT not only on the first one or for all of the at the same time...

The goal is obviously to be able to quickly add and remove extension from the list.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is this what you need? `for i in $(EXT); do find . -name "$$i" -delete; done`

Comment: if it works in a makefile, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
clean:
    for i in $(EXT); do find . -name "$$i" -delete; done
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work because I didn't know the "$$" expression... thanks

Comment: @PinkFloyd No problem. Non-trivial Shell commands are weird to use in make. You also need to keep them in one line or use backslashes.

Comment: I like yours better because it's shorter. Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
# Makefile
.PHONY: clean
clean: CRUFT=$(shell find . -name '*.ext[123]')
clean: ; rm -f $(CRUFT)
```

References:

- [Target-Specific Variable Values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)
- [The `shell` Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function)

Comment: I didn't know about the `-o` option, I'd have used `find . -name "*.ext[123]"`. +1

Comment: Even better; thank you. I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: I chose the other answer because it  is more flexible and easy to add/remove a given extension... but thx

Comment: @PinkFloyd, agreed; @julien-lopez answer is small and clear. Mine has fewer `find` invocations, but uses a complicated regex.